# SQL how you would rewrite this query without crossjoin?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have heard I should avoid cross join so my question is how you would rewrite this query without cross join ?

```
    SELECT p.*, po.*, pt.*
    FROM product p
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT json_agg(name) AS product_options
        FROM product_options po
        WHERE po.p_id = p.id
    ) po
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('tag', tag)) AS tags
        FROM product_tags pt
        WHERE pt.p_id = p.id
    ) pt
    WHERE p.id = 1
```

Here is a fiddle example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be10d/35

the important thing is that I need an array of objects for product options and tags but you can see this on the fiddle the example so I need exact this row with these fields but without cross join

Comment: In combination with a LATERAL derived table there's no need to avoid CROSS JOIN. It's fine as it is.

Comment: However, perhaps you want LEFT JOIN instead? (If you want to include products without product_options or tags.)

Comment: You should focus on solving problems, not on rumors.  There is nothing wrong with your current coding, except that a product with either no tags or no options will not be returned which is a weird thing to want but maybe you do want it to work that way. SelVazi's coding will likely be faster if you return a large fraction of the product table, but will probably be slower given that your WHERE clause looks very selective.

Comment: @jjanes yes I saw the problem that when no tags or no options then it return no rows so in that case I have to use left join the example above but thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an equivalent of your query using `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT p.*, po.product_options, pt.tags
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT p_id, json_agg(name) AS product_options
    FROM product_options po
    GROUP BY p_id
) po ON po.p_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT p_id, json_agg(json_build_object('tag', tag)) AS tags
    FROM product_tags pt
    GROUP BY p_id
) pt ON pt.p_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/96242/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with someone allergic to joins, you don't need to join at all: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/B1rMlZHX)

```sql
SELECT p.*,(SELECT json_agg(name) AS product_options
            FROM product_options po
            WHERE po.p_id = p.id), 
           (SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('tag', tag)) AS tags
            FROM product_tags pt
            WHERE pt.p_id = p.id)
FROM product p
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Both of your correlated subqueries are [scalar](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES), which allows them to be moved up like this.

Comment: Specifically, they are _correlated_ subqueries. (I.e. having a condition referencing a table outside the subquery.)

Comment: @jarlh These are word-for-word OP's, so it's safe to assume they're familiar with the concept. My point was to underline that they are *also* scalar, which allows them to be moved up to select section. I rephrased that now in an edit. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: thank you very much! is it faster then join ?